# setSelected in android for an imageview

Tags: android

I am implementing checkbox  in a listview in android however for this i am using an imageview instead of checkbox.Also i am setting the state selected true and false cases in the xml.When the user clicks on the checkbox for the first time it should be marked as checked for the second click it should display another image.However on the click of this image the state doesn't gets changed.Following is my code:

In the Adapter class:

```
ImageView checkBox1=(ImageView)itemview.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
checkBox1.setTag(new selector(0, position));
```

In the Xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/checkbox_image"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

And finally the checkbox_image xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_box_select" android:state_selected="true"/> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_box" android:state_selected="false"/>   
</selector>
```

Comment: Good article, May help.! http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=525

Comment: If you have read the article and found the solution.. you can paste that part of code with some information as answer and accept that answer.. may be after few hours.

Comment: probably because there is no default state :) in example: `<item android:drawable="@drawable/check_box"/>` second he should put this selector into `background` instead of `src`